# Mask if more then x characters

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a masking plugin (http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) it works, but I am trying to get it to only work once there are 5+ characters in the textbox. Whenever I hit the 6th character, it clears out the textbox and won't accept input anymore.

JS:

```
  <script>
  function convert(){
    if (l.length > 5){
        $("#q").mask('(999) 999-9999');
    }
  }
  </script>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
<input type="tel" class="form-control" name="q" id="q" placeholder="Phone/Order Number" onkeyup="convert()"><br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
</form>
```

if someone could please help me, that would be great. :D

Comment: is there some kind of url where you have deployed the code ,so that we can test it?and where is "l" coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It clears out the textbox because when you apply a mask, the plugin clears the input. You can get around this by passing the `autoclear` option and set it to false. It would also keep attempting to apply the mask, so you'd have to remove the event listener. So ditch the inline event handler, that's a bad way to do event handlers anyway :-)

Something like this would work:

```
$('#q').on('keyup', function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var val = $el.val();
    if (val.length > 5){
        $el.mask('(999) 999-9999', {
            autoclear: false,
            placeholder: ''
        });
    }
});
```

Note that I also set the `placeholder` to an empty string, otherwise when the mask is applied the cursor will be set to the end of the mask placeholder and you'd have to move the caret back a few spaces.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. :)

Answer (score -1):

This will detect a Backspace and revert it from phone number mask to a plain mask

```
$('#q').on('keyup', function(event) {
    var $el = $(this);
    var val = $el.val();
    if (val.length > 5){
        $el.mask('(999) 999-9999', {autoclear: false,placeholder: ''});
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 8){
        $el.mask('999999', {autoclear: false,placeholder: ''});
    }
});
```

Comment: You're creating a nested event listener here, so every time a keyup event happens, a new keydown event listener is created. Please do not do this.